# Best practice in creating belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say we have the following situation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

For simplicity let's say `Ticket` has only some text field `description` and integer `user_id`. If we open User's `views/users/show.html.erb` view and inside User controller we have this code which finds correct user which is selected:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end`
```

Now inside that `show.html.erb` view we also have small code snipped which creates user's ticket. Would this be a good practice in creating it?

views/users/show.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for Ticket.new do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>

  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

controller/tickets_controller.rb

```
def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @user = User.find(ticket_params[:user_id])

    @ticket.save
end

def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:user_id, :description)
end
```

So, when we create a ticket for user, ticket's `description` and his `user_id` (hidden field inside view) are passed to `tickets_controller.rb` where new `Ticket` is created.

Is this a good practice in creating a new object which belongs to some other object? I am still learning so I would like to make this clear :) Thank you.

Comment: why are you fetching the user object in the create method? you are not doing with it anything.

Comment: @OmarMowafi, not at the moment but in the future. I just copy pasted my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this in your form:

```
<%= f.association :user, :as => :hidden, :value => @user.id %>
```

This will pass user_id through your controller to your model and automatically make an association. You no longer need the @user= line in your controller.

Don't forget that the user could modify the form on their end and send any id they want. :)

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations for more info.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the user from the controller using `current_user` so that you protect yourself from anyone that would manipulate the value of the `user_id` in the form. Also I think this way is much cleaner

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for Ticket.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

**controller/tickets_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.user = current_user
    @ticket.save
end

def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:user_id, :description)
end
```

Comment: Thank you but in my case `current_user` is set when new user logs in and this form is manipulated by admin who is creating new tickets for other users. I need to get id's of other users.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to create something for the admin to choose the user, like a dropdown/search. I don't see how the admin can select the user